# Script to Download xls files embeded in a .msg file

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ssis, outlook

There are 1000s of .MSG files on my d drive and each containe an XLS file,as attachemnt.

Is there any way to download these xls files from these .msg file using ssis script or vb or vba?
So that I do not have to open each and every msg file and download the xls files

Comment: Never tried it but I found [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?46112-Outlook-2007-Extracting-attachments-from-msg) I'll look into it a little more and see what I can dig up

Comment: And [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13439/Extracting-mails-and-attachments-from-outlook-2003) which I got from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b593e251-d013-4572-a075-93dc443d66a3/save-outlook-mail-file-msg-using-ssis-2005?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 1):

I also have an other solutuion ,in which the attachments are then deleted from Outlook and in the Body of the mail a remark entered wich attachemnt is saved where; if that is of interest for you let me know.

but for your Need this here should do:

http://www.brainre.org/outlook-vba-macro-to-save-all-attachments-of-marked-emails-including-progress-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` Outlook Object Model function or you can use Redemption (I am its author) and its `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile` method (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) - you can then use `RDOMail.Attachments` collection to loop through all attachments and call `RDOAttachment.SaveAsFile`.